# How to update my same csv file and use it for matching in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, for-loop

There 2 csv files.My first task is to match the contents of both the files with a specified keyword and create a new file with the keyword contents and named as keyword.csv.It is working fine.
Problem part:I want to use the remaining.csv again and again to remove those values which are being matched by the keywords.
program is not throwing any errors but not writing all the content in the csv properly.

```
import csv

handle2 =''
each=''
row=''
cat_var=''
handle1=''
with open('ss.csv') as handle2:
    for each in handle2:
        strng_conv = ''.join(map(str,each.rstrip('\n')))
        print strng_conv
        file_name = strng_conv+'.csv'
        print file_name
        cat_file = open(file_name,'wb')
        cat_var = csv.writer(cat_file,delimiter=' ')
        with open('repaired.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
            handle1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
            for row in handle1:
                if each.rstrip() in row:
                    cat_var.writerow(row)
                    csvfile.close()

                else:
                    with open('repaired.csv','w') as csvfile:
                        handle1 = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=' ')
                        handle1.writerow(row)
                csvfile.close()


        cat_file.close()

csvfile.close()
handle2.close()
```

**ss.csv contains items like**

```
yepme
reebok
adidas
baggit
```

**repaired.csv contains**

```
Waybill Contents    Amount  COD Amount  Type
928049  123456  yepme bag   1109    0   Pre-paid
904096  15116916453 yepme polish    518 0   Pre-paid
922222  52255       puma   abc     522  cod
```

suppose if it matches yepme contents I want repaired.csv shpuld have only row having puma meaning all the leftovers after a match

**sample output files to be created like this-These file contains all the matched data**

```
yepme.csv
reebok.csv
adidas.csv
```

**Repaired.csv at the end should contain those rows which are not matched in any of the keywords**
like I haven't put puma for match so only remaining entry should be of puma left in the repaired.csv

Comment: Removing the `.close()` method will get you the desired result. Nothing is wrong with the code :-)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see that @Andy Kubiak already mentioned this :-) I must get a coffee for myself before coming back to SO today.

Comment: which .close() method all of them?

Comment: Yes. All of them. `with` statement will close the file objects for you. No need to do it manually.

Comment: getting blank csv files :(

Comment: Is the concept right???should i post my csv files data?

Comment: Please post a sample input from the csv files and your desired output... It will be lot easier for debugging :-)

Comment: My guess would be to move the `cat_file = open(file_name,'wb')` outside the for loop and making `open('repaired.csv', 'a')`. But still I need to check the code :-)

Comment: wait I will edit and post

Comment: check I have edited with sample input

Comment: We need a sample output too. What would you want the result of this to be?

Comment: I have given you an overview how my output should be or what I desire from my code

Comment: Added the code :-) Pls check :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would go with a different logic :-)

1. Since ss.csv have only the brand names, load it as a list in the memory
2. Inititalize a output list(empty at the beginning) that will have the `row` objects in your code. These are the rows which do not have any match in the ss.csv
3. whenever a match is found, create a csv file through `"ab"` mode.

Here's the logic in code format :-)

```
with open('ss.csv') as fo:
    all_brands = fo.read().split("\n")

output_row = []
with open("repaired.csv", "rb") as fo:
    handle1 = csv.reader(fo, delimiter=' ')
    for row in handle1:
        row = filter(None, row)
        if not row:
            continue
        if row[2].strip() in all_brands:
            print row[2].strip()
            with open(row[2].strip() + ".csv", "ab") as tmp_write:
                tmp_handle = csv.writer(tmp_write, delimiter=' ')
                tmp_handle.writerow(row)
        else:
            output_row.append(row)

with open("repaired.csv", "wb") as fo:
    handle = csv.writer(fo, delimiter=' ')
    handle.writerows(output_row)
```

This resulted in three files for the input you specified. `ss.csv`, which is untouched. 
repaired.csv

```
Waybill Contents Amount COD Amount Type
922222 52255 puma abc 522 cod
```

yepme.csv

```
928049 123456 yepme bag 1109 0 Pre-paid
904096 15116916453 yepme polish 518 0 Pre-paid
```

Comment: you should not create a new csv file whenever a match is found, only at the end, after you've gathered all of the data - otherwise, if you have a large file, you'll be opening and closing loads of files.

Comment: I am able to create files but not the unmatched content file named as repaired.csv

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_1.py", line 10, in <mod
    if row[2].strip() in all_brands:
IndexError: list index out of range getting this error

Comment: Can you give a `print row` above that line and give the answer here?

Comment: It might be because of an empty line in between. Added a fix for such a bug now.

Comment: Thankyou brah :) thankyou so much but when I am trying to use a larger file it leaves behind certain entries

Comment: It might be because of any extra spaces... Try opening the file in excel with single space as a delimiter. If all are fine there, it will work the same here as well :-)

Comment: Doing that only but still leaving some entries behind

Comment: Any sample from left outs? Because I could not think of another scenario where this would leave entries. Either it is not there in `ss.csv` or the name might be wrong are the scenarios I could think...

Comment: I worked only with MySQL. It has very good support. But I would say all the DBs are just the same and work fine with Python...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you don't fully understand how the IO is working here;

When you do `with X...` what is actually happening under the hood is python calls the `__enter__` method of the object, and then when the scope is left (i.e. the indent level of the `with` statement), it calls the `__exit__` object of the same object.

The following two snippets are equivalent*:

```
with open("file1", "r") as a:
  ...
```

and

```
tmp = open("file1", "r")
a = tmp.__enter__()

...

a.__exit__()
```

(* That is, if you ignore exceptions being chucked out and stuff )

For `File` objects, the `__exit__()` will clean up by closing the file and whatnot - i.e. you shouldn't be closing the file after a `with open(...) as X:`.

And the second thing you're doing, which is perhaps iffy and might not get you the results you desire:

You're looping over the contents of a file, while editing the same file (or maybe at least you think you do). And you're reading the files a couple of different ways.

when you do `for line in file_object` ititerates through the file, moving an internal pointer.

When you open the file, and then read it in using some special reader, you're creating a new object - which will be independent from the actual file. Mixing all of these different methods is likely going to give you results which inconsistent and confusing, and a headache to debug when you make assumptions about how they work.

It will probably be much easier and clearer to just read in the two original files, and then parse them as python objects, rather than opening and closing all of these files. I'll update this if you alter your question so it's a little clearer what you want to do.

try something like this:

```
keywords = []
with open("ss.csv", "r") as keywords_file:
  for line in keywords_file:
    keywords.append(line.strip())


outputs = {}
left_overs= []
with open("remaining.csv", "r") as remaining_file:
  for line in remaining_file:

    for keyword in keywords:
      if keyword in line:
        if keyword in outputs:
          outputs[keyword].append(line)
        else:
          outputs[keyword] = [line]
        break
    else:
      left_overs.append(line)

for keyword, output in outputs.items():
  with open(keyword + ".csv", "w") as output_file:
    for line in output:
      output_file.write(line)

with open("remaining.csv", "w") as remaining_file:
  for line in left_overs:
    remaining_file.write(line)
```

Does that do what you're aiming for?

Comment: It is not creating any file nor any updation in repaired.csv

Comment: Well i haven't tested it at all, add some print statements in after the loops to print out the various variables - check if they're filled

Comment: I've not used many databases in python, and it's a difficult question to ask people anyway, as many people will have far more experience with one db than another. [There's a section in the python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseProgramming) about it though, might be helpful.